# Connecting MFA account to multiple CMDlets

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, office365, exchange-server, powershell-3.0

I am trying to connect to three different CMDlets with one login:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $credential
```

it prompts for login, it prompts for old credentials then prompts for MFA, seems to connect to exchange online but returns the following error:

```
New-ExoPSSession : One or more errors occurred.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\netFramework\ExchangeOnlineManagement.psm1:475 char:30
+ ... PSSession = New-ExoPSSession -ExchangeEnvironmentName $ExchangeEnviro ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-ExoPSSession], AggregateException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.AggregateException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellSnapin.NewExoPSSession
```

Could I please have assistance to connect these three cmdlets at one please?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$credential = Get-Credential`, then pass `$credential` to the commands to login, this way will not work both for `Connect-ExchangeOnline` and `Connect-AzureAD`, you just got the error from `Connect-ExchangeOnline` as the error interrupted the script. For `Connect-MsolService`, when passing `$credential`, it will promote you to login interactively again.

In your case, you may need to login for all of them with an MFA-enabled account. If you want to avoid interactively login, you could use Azure AD App to login the commands.

Reference:

1. [App-only authentication for unattended scripts in the EXO V2 module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/app-only-auth-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps)
2. [Using a Service Principal to connect to a directory in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0)